# App crashes whenever click button and edit text is empty or filled with short alphabets except url

Tags: java, android-studio

and this is my code App crashes whenever click button and edit text is empty or filled with short alphabets except url upload solution as fast as you can its but when i add the url correct it downloades the file without crashing my app is for downloading twitter videos .

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1893)
        at com.gabbaraman.statussaver.Models.TwitterVideoDownloader.getVideoId(TwitterVideoDownloader.java:67)
        at com.gabbaraman.statussaver.Models.TwitterVideoDownloader.DownloadVideo(TwitterVideoDownloader.java:76)
        at com.gabbaraman.statussaver.Activities.Twitter$1.onClick(Twitter.java:31)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22462)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6361)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

public class TwitterVideoDownloader implements VideoDownloader {

```
public Context context;
private String VideoURL;
private String VideoTitle;

public TwitterVideoDownloader(Context context, String videoURL) {
    this.context = context;
    VideoURL = videoURL;
}

@Override
public String createDirectory() {
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                                   File.separator + "My Video Downloader");

    File subFolder = null;
    boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdirs();
    }
    else {
        boolean success1 = true;
        subFolder = new File(folder.getPath()+File.separator+"Twitter Videos");
        if(!subFolder.exists())
        {
            success1 = subFolder.mkdirs();
        }
    }
    assert subFolder != null;
    return subFolder.getPath();
}

@Override
public String getVideoId(String link) {
    if(link.contains("?"))
    {
        link = link.substring(link.indexOf("status"));
        link = link.substring(link.indexOf("/")+1,link.indexOf("?"));
    }
    else {
        link = link.substring(link.indexOf("status"));
        link = link.substring(link.indexOf("/")+1);
    }
    return link;
}

@Override
public void DownloadVideo() {
    AndroidNetworking.post("https://twittervideodownloaderpro.com/twittervideodownloadv2/index.php")
            .addBodyParameter("id",getVideoId(VideoURL))
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .build()
            .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    //Log.e("Hello", response.toString());
                    String URL = response.toString();
                    if (URL.isEmpty())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if(URL.contains("url")){
                        URL = URL.substring(URL.indexOf("url"));
                        URL = URL.substring(ordinalIndexOf(URL,"\"",1)+1,ordinalIndexOf(URL,"\"",2));

                        if(URL.contains("\\"))
                        {
                            URL = URL.replace("\\","");
                        }
                        //Log.e("HelloURL",URL);
                        if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(URL))
                        {
                            String path = createDirectory();
                            if(VideoTitle == null || VideoTitle.equals(""))
                            {
                                VideoTitle = "TwitterVideo" + new Date().toString()+".mp4";
                            }
                            else {
                                VideoTitle = VideoTitle + ".mp4";
                            }
                            File newFile = new File(path, VideoTitle);
                            try {
                                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(URL));
                                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                                request.setDescription("Downloading")
                                        .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                                        .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI)
                                        .setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(newFile))
                                        .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                                        .setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true)
                                        .setTitle(VideoTitle);
                                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                                assert manager != null;
                                long downLoadID = manager.enqueue(request);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                if (Looper.myLooper()==null)
                                Looper.prepare();
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Video Can't be downloaded! Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Looper.loop();
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if (Looper.myLooper()==null)
                            Looper.prepare();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "No Video Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Looper.loop();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (Looper.myLooper()==null)
                        Looper.prepare();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "No Video Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Looper.loop();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(ANError anError) {
                    if (Looper.myLooper()==null)
                    Looper.prepare();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid Video URL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Looper.loop();
                }
            });
}
private static int ordinalIndexOf(String str, String substr, int n) {
    int pos = -1;


        do {
            pos = str.indexOf(substr, pos + 1);
        } while (n-- > 0 && pos != -1);



    return pos;
}
```

}

Comment: looks like your `link` is an empty String

Comment: @Aman Kumar- did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the exception itself, it appears you are trying to get a substring from something that is either empty or shorter than what you wanted to get a substring from. If I had to guess, your indexOf methods are returning a negative index (-1) and you cannot perform a substring on a negative value.

Except debugging your application, and seeing what the value of VideoURL is, I would advise you to do the following:

- In your constructor for the class, ***TwitterVideoDownloader***, check if the videoURL parameter is not null or empty
- If it is, decide on a default string to insert into your VideoURL variable.
- In your ***getVideoId***, before making any checks the passed parameter, first make sure it is not empty or null